# Mysql WHERE IN not working when i put swap the comma seperated value

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, where-in

I have this below weird problem with my mysql query. Correct me if i am wrong.

This below query( Which i have printed from Codeigniter ) giving me result with subject = 4.

```
WHERE `notes`.`subject` IN ('4,2')  GROUP BY `notes`.`id` ORDER BY `created_date` DESC﻿
```

But when i changed this

```
WHERE `notes`.`subject` IN ('2,4')  GROUP BY `notes`.`id` ORDER BY `created_date` DESC﻿
```

It is not returning any result. Why is that?
Lets say i have only one result in table and i am using codeigniter for this.

```
$this->db->where_in('notes.subject',$this->input->get('subject'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is here

```
$this->db->where_in('notes.subject',$this->input->get('subject'));
```

the input variable **subject** is a string for eg `'2,4'`

you can use `$this->db->where_in('notes.subject',explode(",",$this->input->get('subject')));`

which will pass an array to `where_in`

and as per the  [User guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

### Second parameter to where_in() is an array

Comment: Thanks mate. I totally missed that. You are such a pro.

Answer (score 2):

in should have parameter string like

```
 IN ('2','4'); // for varchar
 IN (2,4) // for Integer values
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
WHERE `notes`.`subject` IN ('4','2') ....
```

for Integers

```
WHERE `notes`.`subject` IN (4,2) ....
```